# How do I get current user name and other details in servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a login page named login.jsp for the customer to login.

The checklogin.jsp page where I am checking the user id and password to enter into the customer UI.

I want to have user the username and other details in my servlet.

How can I get this details in servlet page?
The JSP and servlet are simple registration form. I want username and details who is filling the form.

Comment: If i understood ur question correctly, u can set those username in one session attribute and where ever u need in can get that attribute.

Comment: I can save username in session.setAttribute("name",rs.getString(1)).But How can get this in servlet?

Comment: the same way session.getAttribute("name");

Comment: session.setAttribute() is in the checklogin.jsp page. How can I send this in servlet file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you know the user data store it as an attribute:
for ex:

```
<%=request.getSession().setAttribute("currentUser", username);%>
```

then try use this command:

```
<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser"); %>
```

use this code to watch all attributes on console page:

```
<%=Session session = request.getSession();
Enumeration attributeNames = session.getAttributeNames();
while (attributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
String name = attributeNames.nextElement();
String value = session.getAttribute(name);
System.out.println(name + "=" + value);}%>
```

cheers :)

Comment: The problem is, how can I get this in my servlet?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you need to store the details to the session in login servlet.

// get the session, add argument `true` to create a session if one is not yet created.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

session.addAttribute("userName", request.getParameter("userName"));
session.addAttribute("password", request.getParameter("password"));
```

Use this code to get the details in the checkLogin servlet.

```
 // to get the username and password
    String userName = session.getAttribute("userName");
    String password = session.getAttribute("password");
```

Comment: I want the user details in my servlet.

Comment: suppose you use this code inside your servlet. It may be helpful if you could share the servlet code.

Comment: The JSP and servlet are simple registration form. I want username and details who is filling the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this in your jsp.get username and password from
related components and set them in session.

```
<%
  String username = (String)request.getAttribute("username");
  String password = (String)request.getAttribute("password");
  session.setAttribute("UserName", username);
  session.setAttribute("Password", password);
%>
```